# Как исправить ошибку "PuTTY Fatal Error - Network error: Connection refused"?

Tags: ssh, putty

купил виртуальный хост, дали мне ip-адрес, логин и пароль, только подключится к нему немогу, сразу после нажатия появляется консоль и выскакивает ошибка - "PuTTY Fatal Error - Network error: Connection refused" как исправить? может кто-то сталкивался с таким и знайтет как решить
техподержка говорит что я неверно пароль ввожу, этого быть не может, все тщательно проявлял. Брандмауэр Защитника Windows отключал. Толку ноль!

OS: Windows 10,
Клиент: PuTTY

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:
через браузер заходит.
По SSH не работает. Подключится могу лишь через VPN или через 3G-интернет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте Telnet

Comment: аналогичная ошибка

Comment: таже ошибка через клиент FileZilla Client

Comment: не может быть, так если вы не хозяин вашего хоста, то спросите у того, кто может к нему конектиться.

Comment: у техподержки все конектиться, а у меня нет. Дали логин, пароль и сам ip-адрес.

Comment: да, выяснил кстати, конектиться с смартфона по 3G интернету, а с ПК через кабельний интернет нет, но даже если брать интернет через wi-fi на смартфоне такаяже ошибка что и на ПК

Comment: очевидно, что коннект режется провайдером или роутером по протоколам или портам

Comment: или локальным файрволом (это менее вероятно)

Comment: Проверил, на указанном ip 22 порт открыт. Винда обычно не режет исходящие соединения. Если помимо брандмауэра не установлен какой нибудь антивирусный софт. С другой стороны то что телефон не коннектится через WiFi говорит о том, что проблема где то дальше. Проверьте в настройках вашего роутера, не заданы ли там правила на не пропускание 22 порта (по умолчанию их нет, могут быть только если их явно задали). Если нет, то остается 2 варианта: 1. целевая машина не пропускает соединения именно с вашего IP (маловероятно). 2. соединения по 22 порту не пропускает ваш провайдер (обратитесь в поддержку)

Comment: подключал на прямую без роутера не коннектится, провайдер говорит что ничего не знает , они ничего не блокируют. врёт? или возможно у них технические проблеми про какие они сами не знают.

Comment: @KillNoise на любой другой ресурс по ssh зайти можешь?

Comment: собсно, подтвержу слова @Mike - порт на сервере открыт, соединение устанавливается, пароль запрашивается

Comment: Подключитесь через провайдера, через которого это удается, установите утилиту tcpdump, если ее еще нет. Запустите под рутом (или через sudo) `tcpdump -n -i eth0 port 22 and host ! IP` (вместо eth0 подставить имя интерфейса на сервере смотрящего в интернет, IP - адрес с коротого вы зашли, что бы не мешался в выводе) и попытайтесь подключиться через тот канал где не работает, если tcpdump увидит пакеты - то проверяйте фаервол на сервере, блокируется где то там. Если не увидит, значит пакеты на этот конкретный порт не дошли и значит были заблокированы кем то по дороге между вами и сервером

Comment: Что бы не угадывать с какого ip вы зашли можно смотреть только открытие соединений `tcpdump -n -i eth0 "port 22 and tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) != 0"`

Comment: Для  SSH напиши в суппорт, у меня на хосте тоже не получалось соединистя, оказалось они должны были добавить мою IP-ку

Comment: писал в саппорт, сказали что с ихней стороны проблем нет, у них все работает

Comment: @KillNoise найди друга у которого другой провайдер и попробуй подключиться у него на контупере

Answer (score 1):

Наиболее вероятную причину в лице хулиганящего провайдера уже указали, но можно собрать ещё чуть больше информации с помощью `plink.exe` (входит в состав PuTTY):

1. Откройте консоль cmd
2. Выполните `plink -v ваш_хост`

В ответ plink выдаст дополнительную информацию по используемому при подключении протоколу, что также позволит отсечь некоторые причины, типа устаревшего обмена ключами.

Пример подключения:

```
C:\Programs\PuTTY>plink -v <...>
Looking up host "<...>"
Connecting to <...> port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.67
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5p1 Ubuntu-10
Using SSH protocol version 2
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 45:f8:02:48:a0:76:db:93:1a:a4:1a:70:ea:1f:5f:71
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 45:f8:02:48:a0:76:db:93:1a:a4:1a:70:ea:1f:5f:71
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n) n
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
login as: Disconnected: No username provided
^C
```

Comment: Ошибка "Connection refused" однозначно говорит, что порт не прослушивается (либо кто то явно выдает такой ответ) до обмена ключами и т.п. дело точно не доходит

Comment: @Mike да, я в общем-то согласен, тем более, что соединение сразу отклонено, а не по таймауту - значит кто-то где-то порт слушает и негодует.

Comment: ага, на скриншотах мы даже не видим приглашения ввести пароль

Comment: `C:\Users\ivank>plink -v 62.109.25.185
 Connecting to 62.109.25.185 port 22
 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.70
 Failed to connect to 62.109.25.185: Network error: Connection refused
 Network error: Connection refused
 FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused`

Comment: @KillNoise спасибо, действительно, диалог с сервером даже не начинался - его прервали досрочно

Comment: и где проблему искать, у себя на ПК или в провайдера?

Comment: @KillNoise скорее всего провайдер, см. комментарий к вашему вопросу от Mike

Answer (score 0):

По большей видимости у Вас настроен Firewall на внешний интерфейс на сервере. Чтобы разрешить подключение к 22ому порту на Ubuntu (во многих версиях) достаточно выполнить команды:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 22
$ sudo ufw enable
```

Если же у Вас нету возможности выполнить или действия выше ни на что не повлияли, то Вам следует связаться с Вашим хостинг-провайдером для решения данной проблемы.

p.s. В таких случаях подключение может блокировать и провайдер, если ничего уж не помогает, то советую связаться с ним

Comment: операционная система указана в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

1. Проверить `Ping` - доступен ли вообще сервер с вашего IP - **Проверили - работает** (непонятно только почему winMTR пишет no response)
2. Зайти в консоль управления сервером из браузера, проверить диапазоны IP адресов, с которых разрешен доступ к серверу. - **web консоли управления виртуальным сервером, я так понимаю, нету** (а то, что Apache2 на Ubuntu стоит - это очень хорошо - It works!)
3. Если нет web консоли - связаться с провайдером у которого сервер покупали и выяснить, как они сами туда подключаются, поднят ли SSH, и с каких IP адресов доступно подключение по SSH (может быть еще что-то дополнительно в настройках нужно указать, вообще-то, для SSH нужен не только логин-пароль, а еще пара `.pem` ключей - один у вас - один на сервере). **Проверили - SSH поднят, и `.pem` ключи не нужны, т. к. с другого устройства подключение есть без них. Осталось проверить диапазоны IP адресов с которых доступно SSH подключение. Настроить их можно например с того же телефона.**