# Windows(PuTTY) - Android(Termux) SSH ошибка "Fatal Error - Network error: Connection refused"

Tags: ssh, putty, termux

Само подключение по SSH работает. Со своего ПК я работаю в Termux на телефоне. Ошибка же появилась, когда я решил изучить вопрос передачи файлов. Не исключаю конечно ошибку в команде, но судя по [вот этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/746492/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-putty-fatal-error-network-error-connection-refused) сообщению проблема в другом. В моем случае связь с хостом есть (пинг итд)

Команду ввожу следующую (пытаюсь перекинуть файл с телефона на ПК):

```
C:\Program Files\PuTTY>pscp.exe u0_a115@192.168.0.100:/sdcard/Documents/seed.txt "D:\Files\seed.txt"
```

По началу у меня в другом окне было активное соединение с телефоном. После я его закрыл, но ошибка та же. Пробовал так же включить ВПН на ПК (на телефоне тоже был включен, без также попробовал).

Comment: А работать с файлами с помощью WinSCP не пробовали?

Comment: Да ознакомлюсь. Самое главное, чтобы termux все это дело поддерживал, я в частности использую openssh. Хотя у меня рут, поэтому никаких проблем не должно быть

Comment: порт закрыт. это нормально для ms/windows. разбирайтесь с настройками программ, которые могут это делать: «антивирусы» там всякие и т.д. и т.п.